Python MySQL Error: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)" with Remote Database
I am trying to connect to a MySQL database hosted on my website's domain using Python, but I keep encountering the following error:
 mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to
 MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)

my code:
import mysql.connector

try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="",  # My database in not on localhost so here i put my websites domain name and the rest of the creditials
        user="",
        password="",
        database=""
    )
    print("Connection successful!")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(f"Error: {err}")

I have verified the credentials and checked that the database is accessible from a remote host by adding my IP to the "Add Remote MySQL Host" list in my web hosting control panel
but i still get the error message.Is there any special configuration needed for connecting to remote MySQL databases on hosting services?

If you're connecting to localhost, that is very much not a "remote" database though? Have you tried just passing the actual domain as hostname instead? As for special configurations: you'll have to explain your setup before anyone can answer that, the typical setup for a MySQL host is well-documentation all over the web so if that's not what you're using, folks will need to know what's different (or if you're using a specific hosting service, mention which one so that folks who also use that service can pitch in)

I use siteground

in your post, not as a comment. Details about what you use, and how you use it, go in your post (and not as an "edit: ..." section, just [edit] your post to include that information as if it was always there).
